# Margin ignoring top,right,and bottom CSS,HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a span with the word 'Hello' inside it, inside a div with a height of 100px. I'm trying to assign the margin of 50px to the span, top, left, right, and bottom, but for some reason it's only assigning the margin of 50px to the left of the span. I don't know what I did wrong. Please take a look at my code:

**test.php**

```
<style>

div {
border: 1px solid red;
height: 100px;
}

span {
border: 1px solid blue;
margin: 50px;
}

</style>

<div> <span> Hello </span> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display:block to your CSS span

**CSS**

```
span {
display:block;
border: 1px solid blue;
margin: 60px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

*If you give width here it will still work , but makesure you have enough space remaining for span to cover as margn:60px; would throw it 60px left.*

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px; 

}
span {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 60px;
  width: 50px; /* You could also set here or just leave it*/
}
```

```html
<div>

  <span> Hello </span>

</div>
```

Comment: @frosty Yes i would go with Dmitriy. You can also add display:inline-block, well it depends on your requirement

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
}
span {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 50px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div> 
    <span> Hello </span> 
</div>
```

You have to change the `display` property of `span` to `inline-block` or `block` or use any `block` element to achieve the same. I have changed `display` property of `span` to `block`